# Make a custom apache module hook into every requests?

Tags: c, apache, module, hmac

For a project , i needed HMAC authentication at apache level. So i extended the mod_example explained [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) up to this point:

```
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   hmac_module =
        {
                STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
                NULL,            // Per-directory configuration handler
                NULL,            // Merge handler for per-directory configurations
                NULL,            // Per-server configuration handler
                NULL,            // Merge handler for per-server configurations
                NULL,            // Any directives we may have for httpd
                register_hooks   // Our hook registering function
        };


/* register_hooks: Adds a hook to the httpd process */
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{

    /* Hook the request handler */
    ap_hook_handler(hmac_handler, NULL, NULL,APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST);
}

static int hmac_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    // ...
    // some variable definition
    // ...

    // Check that the "hmac-handler" handler is being called.
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "hmac-handler")) return (DECLINED);

    ap_args_to_table(r, &GET);
    ap_parse_form_data(r, NULL, &POST, -1, 8192);

    timestamp = apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "X-EPOCH");
    claimedHash = apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "X-HMAC");
    if (!timestamp){
        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK,APLOG_ERR,HTTP_FORBIDDEN,r,"Timestamp does not exits in request");
        return HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    }
    if(!claimedHash){
        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK,APLOG_ERR,HTTP_FORBIDDEN,r,"There is no claimed hash in the request!");
        return HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    }

    //...
    // calculate timestamp's sha1 hash
    //...

    if(strcmp(claimedHash,encoded)){
        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK,APLOG_ERR,HTTP_FORBIDDEN,r,"Claimed hash and digested values does not match,Claimed:%s , Target:%s",claimedHash,encoded);
        return HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    }

    // Let Apache know that we responded to this request.
    return OK;
}
```

Now, I need to hook this module in apache before it process it further in order to check this request is authenticated or not.

I know that `APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST` parameter in `ap_hook_handler` function make apache to execute this handler before any other handlers.

But i need to know how to make this handler to execute before ANY requests that happen within a specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out my-self. Instead of registering hook at handler phase, I should've registered my module in earlier phase: access_checker.

The final code is available at [github](https://github.com/hats0n/apache-hmac-module/) if anyone is interested.